# External hard disk not working in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive

I am unable to access my external hard disk of seagate in windows 8.
It is a company laptop and i am logging from admin account. 
Model: HP (Elite Book 8470P)

I can see both drives when ever i plug that in but i am unable to access it. Error says this "Access is denied"

Comment: I can see both drives when ever i plug that in but i am unable to access it. Error says this "Access is denied"

Comment: This sounds like a permission problem with your account. We dealing with a personal or company equipment? Please update your question to provide more information required to answer this question. Brian Daniels already ask several questions still left unaswered. This is the second time somebody asked about this problem ( today ) which is odd.

Comment: This might possibly be the same problem as stated [here](http://superuser.com/questions/559267/windows-8-cannot-access-external-drives-location-is-not-available-access-is).

Comment: We're going to need a little more information than this. Do you get error messages? What is the error message? Has it ever worked? How long have you had it? How are you connecting?